# Does iTurmeric support Azure ASB Connector

Tags: olive

We are developing an application that will be deployed on our customer's Azure cloud infrastructure. We have a requirement to integrate with Azure Service Bus (ASB) for delivering messages and integrating with customer's applications. We want to explore if iTurmeric supports ASB connectivity.

We wanted to explore iTurmeric features to achieve ASB communication